# Database good practice: how to make users, which belong to dynamic groups

Tags: java, database, authentication, authorization

I'd like to ask you about good design practice:
I want to design database which will have that kind of functionality:
There will be and users table with login and passwd 
Groups table with id, name and description columns 
And privilages table with privilages (admin, bigboss, user category A, user category B, user category C, ...)
I want to have possiblity to have one user belong to one groups: how to make it, as a column "group_id" in table users or rather a table users_groups with colums user_login and group_id? 
I want to have possibility to give every user from every to none privilage, probably in table groups_privilages

How to make it, so it will be easly implemented using java, java ee, java server faces, mysql, glassfish and jdbc realm? How to make good relation between users and privilages? Are my tables even good to be used?

Admin can create, edit, delete groups at runtime, admin is not mutable.

Answer (score 0):

As it is strictly a one to one relationship put the permission on the user table, as it pertains strictly to the user. If you ever think that it may become a one to many relationship, put it in its own table with userId and groupId. Have the groupId and description in a lookup table.